# AS3 Air application prevent default keys

Tags: actionscript-3, air, netstream

Hi this is a first post for me:

Anyway I am building a video app to allow the user to add cue points dynamically
when the user click the add cue button i have a container slide in from the right with 
some text fields on: Name: Time:, the user then presses enter to add it to a List control and to an XML file. While this container is visible the video is paused, This is where my 
problem is. If the user presses the space bar to have more than one word for the name of the cue point the video starts to play. I think I have to use the preventDefault() function 
but dont know how I would use it in this instance.

The container slides out from a MouseEvent so I can not put say if(e.KeyCode == SPACE) as its in a mouseEvent.

any7 help on doing this would be a great help

Thanks in advance

J

Answer (score 0):

You can try capturing key down events, but give your listener (fourth parameter in [addEventListener()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29)) a high priority, and then do [preventDefault()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#preventDefault%28%29)  and/or [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29)  on the event.

Comment: Taking this further, you'd want to add an event listener in the *capture* phase.  ie, stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown, true);  Then call preventDefault() and/or stopImmediatePropagation() and/or stopPropagation() if it's the space bar.